# Printing from the command line with LibreOffice, lpr commands?

Tags: linux, printing, libreoffice, lpr

I'm trying to print a word document from the command line, but I need to specify printing options that I would normally use lpr for. This is the command I'm using

```
libreoffice -p "filename.doc"
```

I need to be able to specify a username (-U), is this possible? The following doesn't work

```
libreoffice -p "filename.doc" -U username
```

Should this work, or is there another way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't pass `lpr` command line options to `libreoffice`. Two possible solutions are:

1. One step solution (the best solution in my opinion): use [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) outputting a PDF to `stdout` piped to `lpr`:

   ```
   $ unoconv --stdout filename.doc | lpr -U username -P the_printer_name
   ```
2. Three step solution (if you don't want / can't use `unoconv`): use `libreoffice --print-to-file` to a temporary file + `lpr` of the file + delete the temporary file (unfortunatelly *libreoffice* still doesn't support printing to *stdout*):

   ```
   $ libreoffice --headless --print-to-file --printer-name the_printer_name --outdir /tmp filename.doc
   $ lpr -U username /tmp/filename.ps -P the_printer_name
   $ rm /tmp/filename.ps
   ```

Comment: The first command of 2nd solution does not produce any file im `/tmp`. Does it work with `doc` only, not with `odt`?

Comment: It should work with any support file type.

Comment: For those visiting via a search engine (this answer appears to be highly ranked on Duck Duck Go), the `-U username` bit is optional :-)

Answer (score 2):

Under the, $ libreoffice --help

Usage: soffice [options] [documents...]

soffice -p File_name.odt

Worked for me.

libreoffice -p  File_Name.odt just opened the program, lpr just spat at garbage.

Comment: Did the question state this was already attempted and did not resolve?

Comment: soffice -p File_name.odt . worked perfectly for me on linuxmint 20

Answer (score 2):

This is how I print a document using LibreOffice and a CUPS printer on Debian 9:

```
/usr/bin/libreoffice --pt [cupsname] /home/username/filename.odt
```

It works very well without any middle steps.